# Update a database field

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

As part of an application that I am trying to develop is to update records according to the service type. Hence, the Status attribute is graded from 1 to 8 (In progress = 3 and Complete = 5). I made my code but it seems not working as I try to pass values and test update the current service type as the following:

> IF progress then update to 4
>   IF Completed then update 6

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Bend = 4;
        int Complete = 6;

        List<int> Status = new List<int>();

        foreach (int i in Status)
        {
            if (i == 3)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=
              (localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=FLS_DB;Integrated 
               Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;");
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Calls set 
                Service =@Service", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Service", Bend);
                con.Open();
                int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            else if (i == 5)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= 
               (localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=FLS_DB;Integrated 
               Security=True;
               Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;");
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Calls set 
                   Service =@Service", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Service", Complete);
                con.Open();
                int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, for each Status in the list, it should update the Service to wherever appropriate i.e.  if Bend then update to 4 OR if Complete update to 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing a WHERE statement to update only the records that match the conditions `i == 3` or `i == 5`, thus it seems that you don't need a loop.

You just sets Service column to the new values Bend and Complete for all records that contain the value 3 or 5 in the Service column

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(....))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   con.Open();
   // Sets to 4 all records with 3
   cmd.CommandText = "Update Calls set Service=@Service WHERE Service=3" 
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Service", Bend);
   int rowsUpdatedToBend = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   // No need to recreate the command, just change the commandtext and
   // the value of the parameter @service
   cmd.CommandText = "Update Calls set Service=@Service WHERE Service=5" 
   cmd.Parameters["@Service"].Value = Complete
   rowsUpdatedToComplete = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   MessageBox.Show("You have changed " + rowsUpdatedToBend + " rows to Bend state\r\n" + 
                   "You have changed " + rowsUpdatedToComplete + " rows to Complete state");
}
```

Comment: How do I display a message to display alteration is successful?

Comment: Simply displaying the value of returned by ExecuteNonQuery. This value is the number of rows changed by your previous query

Comment: Thank you Steve. I am using console application! Can I use ShowBox ? do you think I should keep the conditions? Sorry I am new on C#  and still learning :(

Comment: Just change MessageBox.Show with Console.WriteLine

Comment: About the WHERE conditions. Yes, otherwise all records will be changed to the last command executed. You should define the limits of your change. IE: All records with state=3 should change to state=4 and so on....

Comment: Steve, I appreciate your help. How do I test this piece of code? Once again I appreciate your help and apologies for keep asking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113895/discussion-between-steve-and-dodi).

Answer (score 0):

1. Does your connection string correct?
2. You are opening the connection twice by if condition
3. Put a break point and check where the programm is going

Assuming the first point is correct; could you try something like this (code edited):

```
string commandText = "UPDATE Calls SET Service=Service + 1 WHERE Service = 3 OR Service = 5;";
string connectionString = @"Data Source=
          (localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=FLS_DB;Integrated 
           Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {            
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);            

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. The connection string is working. 2.I noticed of opening the connection twice for each case 3. How do I test your code I mean how to test the code above? Sorry I am just new to C#

Comment: I debugged the program, it hits the foreach loop and then skips all the codes in between to exit the program !

Comment: Are you sure your Status's list have some expected values?
Btw, the answer below from Steve have a good point for the where clause. 

Do you really need to loop?

Comment: The list Status don't have values in the table! I don't think I need a loop and Steve's previous answer were sufficient through adding WHERE and get rid of the loop. However, how to alter your answer without the loop. Thank you again

Comment: First : delete the for loop
Then add where clause to the sql command and modify the update: string commandText = "UPDATE Calls SET Service=Service+1 WHERE Service = 3 OR Service = 5";
Then, delete this 3 lines : 
     int newValue = i; 
     if (Status == 3 || Status == 5) { newValue = i+1; } 
     else { continue; }
And delete the sql command parameter

Comment: Hiya, Thank you very much for your reply. Could you please alter the code above according to your answer! I am so sorry for keeping asking as I am still new here :)